# use one variable conditioned on another

Tags: r

I am new to `R` so not very apt in it. I am trying to use the values of one variable, conditioned on the corresponding value in the other variable. For example,

```
x 1   2  3 10 20 30 
y 45 60 20 78 65 27
```

I need to calculate a variable, say m, where

```
m= 5 * (value of y, given value of x)
```

So, `given x=3, corresponding y=20 then m = 5*(20|x=3) = 100`

and, `if x=30, corresponding y=27, then m = 5*(27|x=30) = 135`

Could you please tell me how to define m in this case?

Thanks

Comment: What you are asking for appears to simply be 5*y.

[y=20, x=3 -> 100 = 20*5 = y*5]

[y=27, x=30 -> 135 = 27*5 = y*5]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I should have made my question clearer. So, for my case m is a variable, which depends on the response on x & the corresponding values of y. So, say for m i get the following responses on x, 0 1 15 20 3, then corresponding m would be NA, 225, NA, 325, 100. I would like to know if it is possible to define m with a single formula that would give me these values for m, that changes with change in responses in x.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
5*y[x == 3]
## [1] 100
```

And

```
5*y[x == 30]
## [1] 135
```

---

**Edit:** based on you new explanation, it looks like you are looking for `match`, i.e.,

```
m <- c(0, 1, 15, 20, 3)
y[match(m, x)]*5
## [1]  NA 225  NA 325 100
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I should have made my question clearer. So, for my case m is a variable, which depends on the response on x & the corresponding values of y. So, say for m i get the following responses on x, 0 1 15 20 3, then corresponding m would be NA, 225, NA, 325, 100. I would like to know if it is possible to define m with a single formula that would give me these values for m, that changes with change in responses in x.